# Inserting into vector of maps

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of maps:

```
vector<map<string, double>> Fields;
```

and I'd like to insert elements in a function:

```
void insert(const string& fieldName, const double& fieldValue) {
    Fields.insert(pair<string, int>(fieldName, fieldValue));
}
```

But it doesn't find the insert. Any suggestions what would be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Fields is a vector. Either use `operator[]` or `.at` to get the specific map to which you want to insert data.

Comment: Do you want to create a new `map<string,double>` every time `insert` is called?

Comment: Indeed, **it is very suspicious to create a vector of maps that contains a single item**. You probably want a map (Ted answer, part 2) or maybe a vector of pair or something else.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you'd like to create a new `map<string,double>` every time `insert` is called:

```
void insert(const std::string& fieldName, const double& fieldValue) {
    Fields.emplace_back(std::map<std::string,double>{{fieldName, fieldValue}});
}
```

If you instead what to use `fieldName` as *Key* in a `map`, then you shouldn't put `map`s in a `vector` since you then have to search the `vector` for the `map` with that *Key* which is expensive.

An alternative that'll give you fast lookups:

```
std::map<std::string, double> Fields;

void insert(const std::string& fieldName, const double& fieldValue) {
    Fields[fieldName] = fieldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
void insert(const string& fieldName, const double& fieldValue) {

    map <string, double> Field;
    Field.insert(pair<string, double>(fieldName, fieldValue));

    Fields.push_back(Field);
```

Comment: Ok, that's what my first code snippet does too (but with less copying), but are you sure this is what you want? You'll have one `map` per `fieldName`/`fieldValue` pair. How are you going to use that?